# Include HEDA/EDA as dependency for package using SFDX

Tags: unlocked-package, package-dependency, education-data-architecture

I am trying to include HEDA as a dependency for a package that I am trying to create, but when I attempt to create a package version, I get the following error:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create: An error occurred while
>   trying to install a package dependency, ID 04t1R00000126qv: Accounts
>   Missing Organization Feature: Account.RecordType

How can I get around this? I absolutely need to be able to include this dependency because my package requires it. I would create the Account Record Type that is needed, but I m not sure where SFDX is expecting me to do this. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Did you deploy your metadata first? What type of Scratch Org did you create? It needs to be an Enterprise or Developer Edition type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with installing via AppExchange:

1. Generate a password for your Scratch Org user like so `sfdx force:user:password:generate --targetusername SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME`.
2. Go to AppExchange and login with the credentials of your DevHub Production Org
3. Choose 'Install in Sandbox/Scratch Org' and install

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGtdQAG&title=unlocked-package-package-creation-fails-due-to-feature-account-sharing-account-recordtype

I solved it by adding only the account part.